# Why does a div/class within another div/class only inherit certain properties?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to learn CSS and have discovered that a class or div within another div/class does not inherit all properties and I want to know why that is.

Let's say I have the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <p>Hello :)</p>
        <div class="box-1">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad obcaecati ea dolorum dolore facere deserunt. Delectus voluptatem ex unde quae nesciunt, in ratione amet enim saepe corrupti ad magni molestiae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad obcaecati ea dolorum dolore facere deserunt. Delectus voluptatem ex unde quae nesciunt, in ratione amet enim saepe corrupti ad magni molestiae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad obcaecati ea dolorum dolore facere deserunt. Delectus voluptatem ex unde quae nesciunt, in ratione amet enim saepe corrupti ad magni molestiae.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this css applied:

```
body{
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color:#555555;

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;


    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin: 0;
}

.box-1{
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    color: red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

The "Hello :)" paragraph becomes red and bold, just like the CSS of the class defines, so far so good.

What I find weird however is that the "box-1" class with the heading and the lorem ipsum text only become bold but do not become red.

Why is that?

Comment: because you defined a white color

Comment: In your case you also should learn about `specificity weight`. A declared color on an element has a higher specificty weight then a inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance) to see how the inheritance  works. In your code you're setting a color for `.box-1` that overrides the container color.

Comment: But does the container not overwrite the box-1 definition because it's the last one which gets applied?
Or does the order of the classes in the CSS file not matter?

Comment: No, that only applies if you write two styles for the same element or for the same class or id for example two different h1 colors.

Comment: All else being equal, the rule closest to the affected content takes precedence. In this case, `box-1` is nearest the "hello world/lorem ipsum", so its rules apply there. (If you start at the `h1` and start walking up the html hierarchy, the first class you hit is box-1.) There are [other considerations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) regarding precedence but that's what's happening in this specific case.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!